# beamer: repeat variations of a frame

Tags: beamer

In latex beamer I want to do the following:

1. repeat a frame (from some slides before)
2. repeat it again, but make some words grey (or better opaqueness 50%) others red
3. repeat it again but without the grey words from the previous slide

Is there an elegant way to this except of a copy and paste solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) redefines virtually every environment (and many macros) from the standard document classes to accommodate its use of *overlay specification*. As such, what you are after forms part of the basic functionality of `beamer`. You could use a mixture of standard overlay specifications (associated with existing commands, like `\item` from the `enumerate` or `itemize` environments) or by using commands like `\only`, `\uncover`, `\visible` or `\onslide`. The following minimal example, taken from the documentation with slight modifications, tries to highlight this. The code for a single `frame` produces 3 slides, depending on the overlay specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{warsaw}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}% Allow for shaded (transparent) covered items
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
      \item<2-> Let $q$ be the \alt<3>{\alert{product}}{product} of the \uncover<3->{first} $p$ numbers.
      \item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
      \item<1-> But $q + 1$ is \visible<2->{greater than} $1$, thus divisible by some prime
        number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer overlay specification example]

For more information, read the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). On a side note - see how the overlay specification is nested with the transparency of the first `\item`. The word `first` is set to some transparent opacity twice. As it uncovers, the transparency is lost in a stepwise fashion.

In your specific case, it sounds like the `frame` you want to reuse is somewhere at the start of your presentation. Although `\againframe` seems pertinent, it could be that you duplicate the previous `frame` code but this time add some overlay specification.

One possible alternative to duplicating code of an existing `frame` (for ease of changes to the source `frame` being changed automatically) is to use a combination of `\againframe` and some macros. Here's a (very) minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
% Original macro \mymacro essentially does nothing
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1}% \mymacro{..}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=example]% This is frame 'example'
  Here is some \mymacro{content}.
\end{frame}

% Redefining \mymacro to change its argument into an \alert{..}
\renewcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\alert{#1}}%
\againframe{example}% Re-use frame 'example'
\end{document}
```

[image: Using \againframe]

However, LaTeX complains about multiply-defined labels since you're using `\againframe`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes as you pointed out, the frame I want to reuse is somewhere at the start of my presentation. But I don't want to copy the code (because then I have to make changes twice and I want a solution which applies also for similar cases in the future). `\againframe` however don't let me modify things, doesn't it?

Comment: @user4011: The only way you can have access to the original frame content is if you use @cmhughes' answer and define macros that you redefine, or if you copy some part of the previous code. `\againframe` doesn't allow modification of code, nor would capturing the entire frame content in (say) `\BODY` when using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). I'll edit my answer to highlight this to some degree.

Comment: @Werner: `\againframe` sort of let's you modify things.  Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 56):

`\againframe` is your friend here.  Both the frame environment and `\againframe` are themselves overlay-aware.  This means that you can supply an overlay specification to both which says "Only show the frames matching this specification **even if there's code for more**".  So if you have a very complicated frame but put `\begin{frame}<1>[label=repeated]` at the start then only the first slide is shown irrespective of all the other information.  But all that information is kept, so you can later on say `\againframe<2-3>{repeated}` to get the next bit.

I recommend making sure that the overlay specifications don't overlap, which can mean a bit of juggling with the numbers if you want something actually repeated as it is.  Then you have to ensure that, say, slide 2 is an exact copy of slide 1.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31031/86}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=again]
  \frametitle{The Infamous Disappearing Text}

Here is a frame, it's a bit \alert<2-3>{boring}.

It's so boring, we'll see it \only<-3>{{\color<2-3>{gray}twice}}.

\only<3>{But the second time, we'll try to make it more interesting by making some of those words change colour.}

\only<5>{The third time, we'll wave a magic wand to make all the gray words disappear.}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some Comments}
This frame is perhaps even more so.
\end{frame}

\againframe<2-3>{again}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some Comments}
Will this tedium ever end?
\end{frame}

\againframe<4-5>{again}

\end{document}
```

(I shan't post the screenshots.  They're every bit as tedious as the text suggests.)

I used this in a seminar that I gave a year or so back.  You can see the PDFs [here](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Seminars/chern.html) (sorry, the source isn't available there).  The slides to look at are 59-61, 75-76, 81-82, 87-88, 95-97 of the beamer version.  These are all a single *frame*, but shown at different stages.  It won't compile, but the code for that actual frame is:

```
\begin{frame}<1-3 |trans: 1|handout: 1>[label=definition]
\frametitle{\only<1-4|trans: 1|handout: 1>{First}\only<5-6|trans: 2| handout: 2>{Second}\only<7-8|trans: 3|handout: 3>{Third}\only<9-10| trans: 4|handout: 4>{Fourth}\only<11-12|trans: 5-6|handout: 5-6>{Fifth} Candidate\visible<12|trans: 6|handout: 6>{: Fr\"olicher Space}}

\begin{definition}[{\only<1-4|trans: 1|handout: 1>{First}\only<5-6|trans: 2|handout: 2>{Second}\only<7-8|trans: 3|handout: 3|handout: 3>{Third}\only<9-10|trans: 4|handout: 4|handout: 4>{Fourth}\only<11|trans: 5|handout: 5>{Fifth}\only<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5|handout: 1-5>{ Attempt}\only<12|trans: 6|handout: 6>{Fr\"olicher Space}}]
A \alert{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5| handout: 1-5>{smooth}{Fr\"olicher} space} is a triple \((X,\m{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5| handout: 1-5>{I}{C}},\m{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5| handout: 1-5>{O}{F}})\) where:
%
\begin{itemize}
\item \(X\) is a \alt<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{\alert<1-3>{topological space}}{\alert<11>{set}}
\item \(\m{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5>{I}{C}}\only<1-8|trans: 1-3| handout: 1-3>{(U)} \subseteq \Hom{\alt<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{\TopCat}{\Set}}{\alt<1-8|trans: 1-3|handout: 1-3>{U}{\R}}{X}\),\only<1-8|trans: 1-3|handout: 1-3>{ \(U \subseteq \R^m\) open,}
\item \(\m{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5>{O}{F}}\only<1-10|trans: 1-4| handout: 1-4>{(V\only<1-8|trans: 1-3|handout: 1-3>{;\R^m})} \subseteq \Hom{\alt<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{\TopCat}{\Set}}{\alt<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{V}{X}}{\alt<1-8|trans: 1-3|handout: 1-3>{\R^m}{\R}}\)\only<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{, \(V \subseteq X\) open}.
\end{itemize}

\only<1-4|trans: 1|handout: 1>{\medskip}
\pause[2]

\only<5-11|trans: 2-5|handout: 2-5>{
such that

\begin{itemize}
\item \(\m{I}\) and \(\m{O}\) are \alert<5>{compatible},
\item \(\alt<5-6|trans: 2|handout: 2>{\overline{\m{I}}}{\m{I}}\) and \(\alt<5-6|trans: 2|handout: 2>{\overline{\m{O}}}{\m{O}}\) are  \only<5-6|trans: 2|handout: 2>{\alert<5>{also compatible}}\only<7-|trans: 3-| handout: 3->{\alert<7>{saturated}: \(\m{I} = \overline{\m{I}}\), \(\m{O} = \overline{\m{O}}\)}.
\end{itemize}
}
\only<12|trans: 6|handout: 6>{
such that

\begin{itemize}
\item \(\m{C} = \{\psi \colon \R \to X : \phi\psi \in \Ci(\R,\R), \phi \in \m{F}\}\)
\item \(\m{F} = \{\phi \colon X \to \R : \phi\psi \in \Ci(\R,\R), \psi \in \m{C}\}\)
\end{itemize}
}

A \alert{morphism} is a \only<1-10|trans: 1-4|handout: 1-4>{continuous }map \(f \colon X \to Y\) such
that
%
\[
  \phi f \psi \alt<1-2|trans: 1|handout: 1>{\text{ is }}{\in} \Ci \text{ for } \psi \in \m{\alt<1-11|trans: 1-5|handout: 1-5>{I}{C}}\only<1-2|trans:1|handout: 1>{(U)}, \phi \in \m{\alt<1-11|trans:1-5|handout: 1-5>{O}{F}}\only<1-2|trans: 1|handout: 1>{(V;\R^m)}
\]
\end{definition}

\only<3|trans: 1|handout: 1>{
Notation:
\begin{itemize}
\item smooth map = morphism
\item \(\psi \in \m{I}\), \(\phi \in \m{O}\), \(\theta \in \Ci\)
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
```

and the reinvocations are things like:

```
\againframe<6-7|trans: 3|handout: 3>{definition}
```

(looking at it, then it might compile in a normal `beamer` document if you add `\newcommand\m[1]{\mathcal{#1}}` and `\newcommand{\Ci}{C^\infty}` in your preamble.  There might be things I've missed, though.)

Comment: Dead useful, I was looking for a way to insert a small digression into a slide, and this looks like the way to go.

Comment: The link to the PDFs is dead.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the multiply defined labels this produces?

Comment: Never mind. Turns out you get no errors but those warning if you do `\againframe{label}<2-3>` (and wrong behaviour). The correct way around, no warnings are produced.

Comment: @Raphael The warnings occur if your overlay specifications overlap.  So if you have `\againframe{label}<2-3>` and `\againframe{label}<3-4>` then it will complain, but `\againframe{label}<2-3>` and `\againframe{label}<4-5>` won't.  They are only warnings so can be ignored, but it's not hard to ensure no overlaps if it bothers you.

Comment: @LoopSpace Right. If I want an overlop, I should just declare the some uncover-state twice. Regarding warnings, I try to keep warnings to 0 whenever possible (programming practice). Makes it easy to catch new problems as soon as I introduce them.

Comment: can I refer to the last overlay? something like `\againframe{label}<-1>`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\def\mytext#1{Here {\color{#1}is some} text} 
\begin{frame}
 \mytext{black}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
 \mytext{red}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
 \mytext{black}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you wanted to, you could even use

```
\def\mytext#1{\begin{frame}Here {\color{#1}is some} text\end{frame}}
```

and then you wouldn't have to `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`, simply

```
\mytext{blue}
```