# Beamer template simulating a two part blackboard/split screen

Tags: beamer

Given that

- many presentations are viewed on a computer nowadays (think e.g. of lectures in distance teaching)
- in a 16:9 format (wider than lines should be)

I'm looking for Beamer templates that simulate a two part blackboard or a horizontally split screen and allow to rewrite one half of the screen while the other half still shows the previous contents. E.g., I'd like to enter something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{splitscreen}
\newcommand\sometext{Abra kadabra, hokus pokus, simsalabim. }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \sometext\sometext
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
  \sometext\sometext
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \sometext\sometext
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{center}
  \sometext\sometext
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \sometext\sometext
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{center}
  \sometext\sometext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and get something like

[image]

With the beamer template that I'm looking for, it should be possible

- to specify each half screen only once,
- but have it repeated on the next page when presenting the next half-screen
- any uncovering actions of a half-screen should be active only when presenting the material, but be inactive on the next page;
- as a bonus, it would be nice if it is possible to add graphic elements that connect the two sides of the screen (as long as both parts are visible).

Comment: Did you solve this problem eventually?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, I didn't, lack of time, is still on my to-do list. Some things I found that may be helpful: `\againframe` of the `beamer` class, and the questions ["Snapshot like macro for entire beamer frame?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207969/snapshot-like-macro-for-entire-beamer-frame) and ["beamer: repeat variations of a frame"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31031/beamer-repeat-variations-of-a-frame)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at `\againframe`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski My comment from Nov 1, 2021 still describes the status-quo. Still on my list ... sorry. It seems to require some effort, even though it would be quite useful. Please let me know if you find anything into this direction ...

Comment: Thanks for the update! I also think it's doable, the problem is I'm not entirely sure it's useful - I'd be keen to try it in my lectures but probably not at the price of 10s of coding hours :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom paper size and the `columns` environment inside Beamer would give you the following, depending on the specific requirements I could imagine that repackaging the slides outside LaTeX could be a feasible option. Or maybe even inside the LaTeX run with the help of the `pgfpages` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{beamer}
\geometry{paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=9cm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{both}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}

\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{only left}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{only right}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that is not what I'm looking for. In fact, the sample output that I show in my question was generated by a construction exactly like you propose. The problem is that I have to duplicate the contents of each column; it isn't even an exact copy, since any uncovering actions when introducing the contents do not occur in the copy. Probably my question is not stated clear enough: How to specify each half screen only once (with partial uncovering), but have it repeated on the next page, when the next half screen is presented.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207969/snapshot-like-macro-for-entire-beamer-frame This could provide a way, automatically saving a frame and reusing it later

Comment: Thanks for this reference, this looks promising, something to start from. I'll try ...