# How can I repeat frames as handout with one pause for recapitulation?

Tags: beamer, frame

I want to avoid duplicated frames in the style (see !!! for the difficult problem):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Configuration Drift}

    is a derivation of the ``Single Source of Truth'' (the CM code).

    \vspace{1em}
    It is caused by:

    \pause

    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item manual configuration changes by administrators
    \item manual configuration changes by end users
    \item differences in updates (e.g., skipped or failed updates)
    \item failed attempts to change configuration
    \item applying different versions of CM code
    \item non-idempotent CM Code
    \item \dots
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% ... somewhere else

\section{Recapitulation}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Configuration Drift}

    \pause % in the recapitulation the answer should be hidden in the beginning

    is a derivation of the ``Single Source of Truth'' (the CM code).

    % now here no \pause is needed anymore,
    % as it should be like handout after I revealed the answer

    \vspace{1em}
    It is caused by:

    \begin{itemize} % !!! recapitulation should be like handout, so no [<+-| alert@+>]
    \item manual configuration changes by administrators
    \item manual configuration changes by end users
    \item differences in updates (e.g., skipped or failed updates)
    \item failed attempts to change configuration
    \item applying different versions of CM code
    \item non-idempotent CM Code
    \item \dots
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I know there are many ways to repeat with againframe and overlay specifications, e.g. [beamer: repeat variations of a frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31031/beamer-repeat-variations-of-a-frame)
but I did not find a way to remove the `[<+-| alert@+>]` in the againframe.

What I ideally would like is some "repeat frame, with one \pause after frametitle and then show everything like it would be an handout". Is something like this available?

best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively show certain overlays in the original frame as well as in the againframe like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<2->[label=foo]
    \frametitle{Configuration Drift}
    
    \pause

    is a derivation of the ``Single Source of Truth'' (the CM code).

    \vspace{1em}
    It is caused by:

    \pause

    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item manual configuration changes by administrators
    \item manual configuration changes by end users
    \item differences in updates (e.g., skipped or failed updates)
    \item failed attempts to change configuration
    \item applying different versions of CM code
    \item non-idempotent CM Code
    \item \dots
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% ... somewhere else

\section{Recapitulation}

\againframe<1,9>{foo}
\end{document}
```