# pause and againframe for recapitulation

Tags: beamer, warnings

Similar to [Multiply-defined labels warnings with frame labels in Beamer with againframe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/multiply-defined-labels-warnings-with-frame-labels-in-beamer-with-againframe) I get multiply-defined labels warnings. But the workaround given there does not work for following situation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=example]
    \frametitle{Examples}

    This text is to be shown:

    \pause

    In the recapitulation, this text should first get hidden
\end{frame}

\againframe<1,3>{example}

\end{document}
```

```
  Label `example' multiply defined
  Label `example<1>' multiply defined
```

The goal is: to first have a sequence, and then to recapitulate the previous slide with less (or different) sequence steps (2).

Related but different is my previous question [How can I repeat frames as handout with one pause for recapitulation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595647/how-can-i-repeat-frames-as-handout-with-one-pause-for-recapitulation) which is even more difficult (and still unanswered).

Comment: (I just posted an answer to the other question which seems to work as well with your code here, so I closed as duplicate)